# Efficient method of changing step sizes to approach an unknown limit?

Tags: performance, computer-science

I will be some test software soon that will be testing the power output limit of a sort of power supply. I am trying to step through power increments with efficient speed and step sizes. Step size is currently what is on my mind. I'd like to see if there is any literature or method for determine step size as a limit is approached.

I have several variables I will check during the load increment. These variables will inform me of how close I am to certain limits within the power supply. Exceeding any of these limits will cause a failure. Whatever the power output was in that instant is the power output recorded for that test with the conditions set during that test. My goal is to use these variables as indicators of how close I am to a failure and adjust my step size accordingly.

I could just decide on some curve and adjust as needed, but I am self taught in programming so there is a world of knowledge on the CS side I am missing. This seems a good opportunity to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to suggest something without knowing more about the variables that will inform you of how close you are to certain limits within the power supply.

With everything else a black box, I'd start with something like this:

```
double EPSILON = 0.1

double findLimit() {
  double stepSize = 1;  
  double safeValue = 0;  // proven safe

  while (stepSize > EPSILON) {
    if (testPowerSupply(safeValue + stepSize)) {
      safeValue = safeValue + stepSize;
      stepSize = stepSize * 2;
    } else {
      stepSize = stepSize / 2; 
    } 
  }
  return safeValue;
}
```

Comment: I have values like voltage, current, and capacitance on the line. I know the limits for these and other values. I get new measurements for each of these values many times per second. This allows me to know how close I am to exceeding any given parameter so I can change the step size to suit the one closest to failure.

I can write the software to change the step size dynamically. I am interested in finding, if it exists, some optimal step method. There are proofs and efficiency methods for all sorts of things. I wanted to see if something like this existed and could be applied.

Comment: If you know how close you are to failure, doesn't that mean you know how far to go?